# How to check if an id in array exceeds the number of occurrence

Tags: laravel

I am about to check if the IDs in an array do not exceed the total occurrence from another field.

Example db records

##### `sponsorship_items` table

| id | title | spots |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sponsor1 | 2 |
| 2 | sponsor2 | 5 |

##### `user_sponsorships` table

| id | sponsorship_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

Initial Laravel code:

```
public function compare()
{
  $userSponsorship = UserSponsorship::selectRaw('sponsorship_id, count(*) AS total_sponsors')
                            ->groupBy('sponsorship_id')
                            ->get();
  // more codes here...

}
```

Example input:

```
$input = [1, 2]; // sponsorship_id
```

Expected:

```
$response = [
   "sponsor1" => 0, // since there are only 2 available spots
   "sponsor2" => 4, // since there are 5 spots for sponsor2 and only one occured
];
```

How can I get the accurate response based on the sample data above?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the "sponsorship_items" and "user_sponsorships" tables I have figured out the solution.

Here is the code :

```
$userSponsorship = UserSponsorship::selectRaw('sponsorship_id, count(*) AS total_sponsors')
    ->groupBy('sponsorship_id')
    ->get()
    ->keyBy('sponsorship_id');

return collect([1 => 'sponsor1', 2 => 'sponsor2'])
    ->mapWithKeys(function ($title, $id) use ($userSponsorship) {
        $spots = SponsorshipItem::find($id)->spots;
        $occurrences = $userSponsorship->get($id)->total_sponsors ?? 0;

        return [$title => max(0, $spots - $occurrences)];
    })
    ->toArray();
}
```

Hope this will help you.